# Dr. Strangelove: Nuclear Bombs and Special Effects

Tags: stanley-kubrick, dr-strangelove

I just finished watching Dr. Strangelove for the second time in my life, the last time was when I was a teenager and I have to say I enjoyed it much thoroughly nowadays. So many outstanding performances I just can't choose what I liked most about it.

I suppose I had some more mundane questions about the movie though. Some of the flying special effects seem a bit dated, but I was surprised by one scene in the end when the ICBM complex comes into sight. How did he do that? Did Kubrick literally build a model cockpit along with a model military base and move the camera along with the model plane?

[image]

Also I was interested in some of the nuclear bomb footage at the end of the movie. One scene with two nuclear bombs going off at once:

[image]

And another image with a cannon shooting off a nuclear bomb:[image]

The footage seems to be real, are they real nuclear tests? The cannon footage is especially perplexing, I'm assuming they didn't have anyone shoot off that cannon but it was done remotely, does anyone have more info about it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a cannon, but those are real nuclear weapon tests.

Comment: The cannon you see are not shooting off nuclear bombs. That was a different test, Upshot-Knothole Grable. Your image is from Ivy Mike, the cannons seen are anti aircraft guns (hence high angle) which fire smoke rounds for free air pressure measurement.

Comment: "Did Kubrick literally build a model cockpit" IIRC not only did he build a model cockpit, but he did it so well that the military investigated him for spying.

Comment: [The Atomic Café - 1982 Documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lF0r1OdDIME). See also, *Trinity and Beyond* but that's pay walled these days.

Answer (score 14):

The shots of the plane exterior & interior were done using the same method, just on two different scales.

The exterior is a model, the interior is a full-size set, of course.

[Rear Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rear_projection) is a technique whereby live action takes place in front of something similar to a cinema screen, except the image is projected from behind instead of in front like a regular cinema.
The camera can then directly shoot this apparently composite image without any post production necessary.

There's a limitation as to how much detail you can achieve this way, it always tends to look slightly fuzzy or grainy compared to the live action, though in later years it did become harder to spot.

If you look at the plane exterior you can see the camera shake on the real aerial footage isn't matched by the model plane, which appears to be mounted at a fixed distance & is free only to tilt left to right.
The interiors look a bit better because they have the ability to shake the camera inside the cockpit, masking the discontinuity a little better.
The 'ride' at the end is somewhere between the two scales.

These days there is the rather magnificent ["Volume"](https://www.starwars.com/news/the-mandalorian-stagecraft-feature) which I would imagine can replace this technique entirely, if you have the budget.
Essentially this is a very similar technique, meaning the compositing is done live in camera, with an advanced playback system allowing the backgrounds to be done in CGI & the lighting being already tone-mapped, so you really don't 'see the join' any more.

The 'atom bomb' footage at the end is real, using shots from actual nuclear tests.

Comment: ..was part of a testing group doing lower budget Stagecraft ideas and options ('Volume' refers rather to the LED screen setup) for smaller studios during pandemic (as staff were cut or furloughed), essentially half of volume and a much smaller 'brain bar'. As with anything there was always a risk of 'over use' as it came to be seen as a cheaper way to get some vfx done, unfortunately. Like any other tool, it works for some circumstances but not all. It does hark back to the old matte painting on glass screens that allowed live filming, but with much greater freedom of course.

Comment: @blobbymcblobby - cool. I've seen similar things in situ, but not the 'workings' as such, only the screens themselves. I worked on a TV show earlier in the year where one entire wall of one of the sets is supposed to be a 'view of outdoors'. I tried to estimate how many screens it was made up from when I could see the back of it. Perhaps something in the order of 2000 individual screens, though as it was curved there was no point from which you could properly count how wide it was. From the inside you cannot see the joins, even right up to it. Very impressive stuff.

Answer (score 3):

The interior cockpit was a very detailed and accurate set. From "Inside the Making of Dr. Strangelove", a documentary included with the 40th Anniversary Special Edition DVD of the film, [summarised on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove#Sets_and_filming):

> Lacking cooperation from the Pentagon in the making of the film, the set designers reconstructed the aircraft cockpit to the best of their ability by comparing the cockpit of a B-29 Superfortress and a single photograph of the cockpit of a B-52 and relating this to the geometry of the B-52's fuselage. The B-52 was state-of-the-art in the 1960s, and its cockpit was off-limits to the film crew. When some United States Air Force personnel were invited to view the reconstructed B-52 cockpit, they said that "it was absolutely correct, even to the little black box which was the CRM." It was so accurate that Kubrick was concerned about whether Adam's team had carried out all its research legally.

Answer (score 2):

### The footage of nuclear explosions at the end comes from actual footage filmed during actual U.S. atomic weapons tests.

#### This footage is considered to be in the public domain, thus the reason why Stanley Kubrick was able to use them as a part of that montage at the end of the film.

While other answers focus on the use of models, custom built sets and rear projection filming, this answer focuses on actual atomic weapons explosion footage.

> The footage seems to be real, are they real nuclear tests?

Yes. The footage is real and comes from 1950s U.S. atomic weapons tests.

As the Wikipedia page for [*Dr. Strangelove*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove) explains; I have added YouTube links to key moments in each test:

> This footage comes from nuclear tests such as shot ["Baker" of Operation Crossroads](https://youtu.be/gm79CUjqcZ8) at Bikini Atoll, the [Trinity test](https://youtu.be/7dfK9G7UDok), a test from [Operation Sandstone](https://youtu.be/KNtwRUenOzU) and the hydrogen bomb tests from [Operation Redwing](https://youtu.be/Ja67my7ghk4) and [Operation Ivy](https://youtu.be/GY2jHuZjQcY).

But you ask about the cannon footage specifically:

> The cannon footage is especially perplexing, I'm assuming they didn't have anyone shoot off that cannon but it was done remotely, does anyone have more info about it?

Based on [a comment by blobbymcblobby](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/118555/dr-strangelove-nuclear-bombs-and-special-effects/118595?noredirect=1#comment207870_118595) that shot can be seen at about 0:23 to 0:24 seconds into [this Ivy Mike video](https://youtu.be/Q3ezhvCzWCM?t=24) and is not a cannon., “…in several versions of Ivy Mike footage there is a bit more detail on the apparatus poking up at the sky at the bottom of the screen - showing that these are Anti Aircraft Artillery (hence high angle), used for firing smoke rounds for free air pressure measurement.”

Here is a screenshot of that specific moment that was used in used in *Dr. Strangelove*:

[image]

FWIW, there *was* indeed a [M65 atomic cannon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M65_atomic_cannon) (aka: *Atomic Annie*) that was used in tests. This short video shows that cannon in action in 1953. But this footage was not used in *Dr. Strangelove* at all:

More amazing, and in my opinion horrifying, footage of U.S. atomic blast tests can be found [here on the official YouTube channel of Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLvGO_dWo8VfcmG166wKRy5z-GlJ_OQND5).

Comment: I mentioned Grable above in an earlier comment - that would be the only time that type of shell would be fired. The footage is clearly not from Grable, and looks to be from Ivy Mike, and in several versions of Ivy Mike footage there is a bit more detail on the apparatus poking up at the sky at the bottom of the screen - showing that these are Anti Aircraft Artillery (hence high angle), used for firing smoke rounds for free air pressure measurement.

Comment: Ah, yes, perfectly silhouetted! :)